# how typescript type declaration order does not matter?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I was wondering how type declaration order does not matter when I tested it on typescript playground

Here is the link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigMQPYYNwFgBQok6WKUAzsAgJYB2A5nvgQQMYa2VQBGiAXLERkA5AAsIAGwkZhQA

This question related to if it is safe to disable eslint rule only for type definition files (.ts). for example:

```
/* eslintrc.js */
overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/*.ts'],
      rules: {
        'no-use-before-define': 'off',
      },
    },
]
```

Comment: Why should it matter? It's all compile-time anyway, so it's not like processing in order makes any more sense.

Comment: Aha, so typescript only works for compile time the order does not matter. Is it right?! https://learning-notes.mistermicheels.com/javascript/typescript/runtime-type-checking/#strictness-of-runtime-checking Didn't know it before 

Comment: "*if it is safe to disable eslint rule only for type definition files (.ts)*" 1. type definition files are ".d.ts" 2. [the ESLint `no-use-before-define`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-use-before-define) is for runtime code. Disabling it won't really matter for TS type definitions. [The @typescript-eslint `no-use-before-define` rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-use-before-define.md) is separate one and mostly works as style enforcement. It's also configurable. Not sure why you'd completely disable it.

Comment: "*so typescript only works for compile time the order does not matter. Is it right?*" [Yes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure). It's a well-known fact. It *compiles to JavaScript*. It's one of the key features of TS.